# Value not fetching from helper.js to controller.js in aura for the first click of a button

Tags: aura

I set a value for 'statusValue' in helper.js, it is not picking in controller.js file immediately after reload of the page. It is working fine from the 2nd click onwards.

If I put whole controller.js method in helper.js it is working, but I can't do it because other components are dependent on this helper method.

I understand that helper method is working async, but how can I solve this problem?

```
 component.cmp ---

 <aura:attribute name="statusValue" type="String"/>

 <lightning:button variant="brand-outline" label="Approve" onclick="{!c.approveRecord}" />

controller.js ---

approveRecord: function (component, event, helper) {
helper.getRecipientStatus(component); ---- this is executing async
var status = component.get("v.statusValue");
console.log("v.Controller " +component.get("v.statusValue")); // value showing undefined on first click
if (status == "In Review"){
    component.set("v.modalHeader", "Approve");
    component.set("v.showApproveRejectModal", true);
    component.set("v.actionType", "Approve");
} else if (status == "Approved/Rejected"){
    component.set("v.commentsLabel","Comments");
    component.set("v.comments",null);
    component.set("v.modalHeader",'Approve');
    component.set("v.showModal",true);
    component.set("v.actionType",'Approve');
}else {
  helper.showConfirmationToast(
    component,
    "error",
    "Please “Approve or Reject” the Recipients before this action",
    "Error!"
  );
}},

helper.js ----

getRecipientStatus: function (component) {

    var action = component.get("c.getStatus");
    action.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.statusValue", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("v.statusValue " + component.get("v.statusValue"));  //correct value is fetching here
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
```

Apex ----

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getStatus(String recordId){
    String statusValue = '';
    List<Recipient__c> giftRecips =  [SELECT Id,Name,Status__c,Recipient_Name_Lookup__r.Name,Recipient_Name__c,Recipient_s_Company_Name_Lookup__r.Name,
                                           Recipient_Employer_s_Entity__c,Recipient_Title__c
                                           FROM Recipient__c
                                           WHERE Gift_Id__c =: recordId
                                          ];
    for (Recipient__c giftRecord : giftRecips){
        if (giftRecord.Status__c == 'In Review'){
            statusValue = 'Event Level Review';
        }
        else if (giftRecord.Status__c == ''){
            statusValue = 'noStatus';
        }
        else statusValue = 'Approved/Rejected';
        
    }
    System.debug('statusValue'+statusValue); //correct value is fetching here
    return statusValue;
}
```